# How to restrict certain media types from being uploaded to custom media library folder in Sitecore 8 Content editor

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-media-library

i would to create two differents custom media folder templates in the Sitecore 8 media gallery:

- Images Folder
- Videos Folder

When clicking the upload files button, the first will accept only images, the second will be accept only videos. Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a market place module for that, it's called Media Library Policeman.

Does exactly what you need.

You can download it here: https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Media_Library_Policeman.aspx

Comment: Tnx! It's also for 8.2 mvc version?

Comment: I'm not sure. But if it doesn't, it should point you in the right direction so you can write your own code which will do the trick

Comment: If i wanted to implement a custom solution, I could do this programmatically by extending (f.e.) MediaRequestHandler. This is a good practice or there are any other better approaches you can suggest to me?

Comment: I found this article, seems to be another possible solution: https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Media/Prevent%20Files%20from%20Uploading.aspx